# Swagger token authorization

Tags: authorization, swagger, token

Is there way for authorization where I target URL first and I define 3 fields (client, username, pass) with GET method so it return token which is used for authorization?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean how to _write an OpenAPI definition_ for a GET endpoint that has 3 parameters (client, username, pass) and returns a token? Or do you mean something else, e.g. how to implement authorization in your API's code?

Comment: Yes Helen, I meant the first one - to write an OpenApi definition.

Comment: How does the GET request actually look like? Have you already tried writing an OpenAPI definition for it? If yes, what part are you having problems with? If no, check out https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/ and https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/ to get started.